# Can a non-nullable int be null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, null

I modified ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Extending Identity Models in order to use int keys instead of string (GUID) as indicated on [ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Extending Identity Models and Using Integer Keys Instead of Strings](http://johnatten.com/2014/07/13/asp-net-identity-2-0-extending-identity-models-and-using-integer-keys-instead-of-strings/) and modified the logic on some methods methods as shown below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    ViewBag.RoleNames = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
    return View(user);
}
```

to this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id)
{
    if (id > 0)
    {
        // Process normally:
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        ViewBag.RoleNames = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
        return View(user);
    }
    // Return Error:
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

On the other hand, instead of changing logic, I just want to change the condition in if block, but I am not sure what is the best way to check null values for int?

The original method is like that:

```
if (id == null) //id is string
```

As I had to change string to int type, I need to check null something like that:

```
if (id !> 0) //id is int
```

Any idea?

Comment: Int cannot be a null, your best bet is to use -1 as a null value (assuming it will never be used normally)

Comment: `If (id == 0)`. But better to make it `int?` (nullable) so that you can use `if (!id.HasValue)`

Comment: This question is unclear. The method you show is an action method, so it's called through MVC. What intended use cases do you have? What error handling do you have in place? What happens when a user omits the `id` parameter when calling this action method? What do you want to happen when they request the page with `id` set to `0`? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I should not use nullable int as the id parameter also dependent. So, it ok using **if (id == 0)** instead of **if (id == null)**? Thanks...

Comment: @PatrickHofman **Not duplicate** as requiring non-nullable. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Any idea regarding to the last comment sent to you?

Comment: You can't make something that isn't nullable `null`. The key point of your question is: how to allow the value to be null. The dup answers that.

Comment: Why not make it nullable? But I assume you wont have records in your database with `id = 0` so it should be OK.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because using int? causes "cannot convert from int to nullable int..." error and I do not want to modify the related class parameters.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot, I deciden to use if (id == null).

Comment: Then use `id.Value` for the places you need an int.

Answer (score 1):

A normal integer cannot be null, the default value is 0. If you want a [nullable integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) you need to use `int?` Then you can check if it's null or 0 like so:

```
if (id == null) //!id.HasValue
{
    //some stuff
} else if(id == 0) {
    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use nullable, is it possible to use this without nullable?

Comment: @Clint are you asking _"Can a non-nullable int be null"_?

Comment: @ClintEastwood no that's not possible

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok, updated.

Comment: @LeonHusmann What about **if (id == 0)**?

Comment: Sure you can check if your int is 0 or not.